# Signalling Game - Extensive Form

Tags: game-theory, signaling

I am drawing the extensive form for Beer or Quiche game. Is there any difference in the following two representations or can either one can be used for representing the same information?

[image]

Comment: The left one has no specification of the distribution of types.

Comment: And the right one does not assign players to the decision points, thus neither one is perfect (: